# Reduce space between plots ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, spacing, bookdown

I am working with `bookdown` and the `emmeans` package. I am trying to render a pdf where I can fit a series of plot with minimal space between each other

````
```{r 3AeMixEffCmass,out.width = c("32%","32%","32%"), fig.align = "center", fig.pos="!h",fig.show = 'hold',fig.cap='(ref:3AeMixEffCmass)', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}

### plot letter identifier:
library(grid)
my_grob = grobTree(textGrob("A1", x=0.85,  y=0.95, hjust=0,  gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize=15, fontface="italic")))


library(ggplot2)
### Order the levels for printing:
cld.mixed_C_L$managem = factor(cld.mixed_C_L$managem, levels=c("WTH", "CH", "CHF")) 
### reset row number: 
cld.mixed_C_L<- with(cld.mixed_C_L, cld.mixed_C_L[order(managem),])
rownames(cld.mixed_C_L) <- NULL
````

`cld.mixed_C_L` looks like this:

```
cld.mixed_C_L <- structure(list(managem = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("CH", 
+ "CHF", "WTH"), class = "factor"), response = c(2.46142878854869, 
+ 2.47526369032351, 3.25797765207699), SE = c(0.111893590886356, 
+ 0.112522508873481, 0.148103743733873), df = c(5.22163854368496, 
+ 5.22163854368496, 5.22163854368496), lower.CL = c(2.10382917999276, 
+ 2.11565412905959, 2.78465437801484), upper.CL = c(2.87981160196529, 
+ 2.89599809934785, 3.81175432945472), .group = c("a", "a", "b"
+ )), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 2L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### create plot:

```
plot.mixed.lme<-ggplot(cld.mixed_C_L,aes(x = managem,y=response,color= managem, label=.group))+ 
        theme_bw()+
        geom_point(shape  = 15, size   = 4) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin  =  lower.CL,ymax  =  upper.CL),width =  0.2,size  =  0.7)+ 
        theme(aspect.ratio = 2/1) + 
#### following lines adds legend inside the boxplot:
        theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0),
        legend.direction="vertical",
        legend.box="vertical",
        legend.box.just = c("top"), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill=alpha('white', 0.4)))+
        #removes legend:
        guides(fill = FALSE, color= FALSE) +
#### remove axis labels:
        theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
#### move significance letters:
        geom_text(nudge_x = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3),
                  nudge_y = c(0, 0,0),
                  color   = "black") +
#### set colours of the boxes:
        scale_color_manual(values = c("#333333", "#333333", "#333333"))+
        annotation_custom(my_grob)
### print three plots as example: 


plot.mixed.lme
plot.mixed.lme
plot.mixed.lme
```

The result on the final pdf document looks as follows:
[image]

I have been trying to figure out how to reduce the space between plots, but so far I've had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

## Issue with sizes of plots not matching

(see comments)
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? You don't provide your data (`cld.mixed_C_L`).

Comment: hi @Lyngbakr  I added the table sorry for the inconvenience and many thanks for your help.

Comment: The snapshot of the pdf shows three different plots but in the example these are the same just to make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `out.width = c("32%","32%","32%")` from the chunk options and use `cowplot`'s `plot_grid` function, like this:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plot.mixed.lme, plot.mixed.lme, plot.mixed.lme, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Lyngbakr, this is very useful many thanks. Just as a follow up to your solution, suppose I have to print two rows, one with 3 and the other with 6 plots. How would I go maintaining the size of the plots equal ?

Also I have noticed this solution does not scale the axis' names so they become overlapped if the plot is too small (e.g. WTH,CH, CHF). Any ideas for this?

Many thanks.

Comment: @BAlpine To have two rows – one row with three plots, one with six plots– you could have a grid of 2×6. So, `nrow = 2` & `ncol = 3`. In the row with only 3 plots, fill the other three slots with `NULL`.  Something like this: `cowplot::plot_grid(p, p, p, NULL, NULL, NULL, p, p, p, p, p, p,nrow = 2, ncol = 6)`.  If you want to organise your plots so that the top three are centred, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954119/1552004) approach with `grid.arrange`. Regarding axis labels, I'd just alter them in their definition (i.e., in `ggplot2`) to get them to look right.

Comment: thanks again for your response. I have noticed that if I am to print two plots from different tables, lets say the second one being (see next comment for cld.mixed_C_F table) then they get printed in different height. Any idea on how to make them equal in size? Thank you and sorry to keep bothering you

Comment: cld.mixed_C_F <- structure(list(managem = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("CH", "CHF", "WTH"), class = "factor"), response = c(26.3307005296252, 52.3472820920016, 57.333285750475), SE = c(4.05296874590397, 7.74973535286334, 8.67113452769207), df = c(6, 6, 6), lower.CL = c(15.9077507529436, 30.4174214319357, 34.033878734242), upper.CL = c(43.5828924621863, 83.3354273544769, 93.2435326641693), .group = c("a", "a", "a" )), row.names = c(3L, 1L, 2L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @BAlpine Can you edit your original question to demonstrate the height issue with code, pictures, etc., please?

Comment: I added the image with the problem. I used the line:

cowplot::plot_grid(p1,p2,p3,NULL,NULL,NULL, nrow = 1, ncol=6)

This also creates extra space between the plot and the caption. Thank you

Comment: @BAlpine Try using the `plot_grid` parameter `align = "v"` for vertical alignment.

Comment: Thank you so much. Still trying to figure out the space in between plots and caption but everything else works.

Comment: @BAlpine You're welcome! For that, using `plot.margin` in the `theme` function when creating the plots originally in `ggplot2` might be your best bet.

Comment: I am not sure about `plot.margin`.If you look at my very first image the plots are much closer to the caption.

Comment: @BAlpine Yeah, you're right. Setting `fig.asp` in the chunk options to something like 0.5 seems to help a bit compared to the default value.