# rasterVis - setting the bottom plots in the middle with levelplot

Tags: r, lattice, gridextra, levelplot, rastervis

I am using the awesome `rasterVis` to create a panel with maps that have the same extent (i.e. same spatial coverage) but that show different features (i.e. each with its own legend).

This is what it looks like so far:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gridExtra)

# make-up data
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
s <- stack(r, r*2, r*3, r*4, r*5)
names(s) <- paste0("Field ",seq(1,5))

# pre-allocate list
l <- vector("list", length=nlayers(s))

# define theme for plots
my.theme <- rasterTheme(region=brewer.pal(11,'RdYlGn'))

# loop over stack layers to fill list
for (n in (1:nlayers(s))){
  
  l[[n]] <- levelplot(s[[n]], margin=F, main=names(s[[n]]), par.settings=my.theme)
  
}

# plot combined maps
grid.arrange(l[[1]], l[[2]], l[[3]], l[[4]], l[[5]], ncol=3)
```

[image]

Note that the default positioning for the maps is:

```
a b c
d e
```

However, I would like to have a finer control on the positioning. Specifically, I would like to "center" the bottom two facets in order to distribute the void space more evenly on the sides of the plot.

In other words, the placement I am looking for  would look like:

```
a b c
 d e
```

How can I achieve this? I looked up the documentation for ([`grid.arrange`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html)), but couldn't find any option the would solve my problem.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `cowplot::plot_grid` inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52953980)

```
library(cowplot)
top <- plot_grid(l[[1]], l[[2]], l[[3]],
                 ncol=3)
bottom <- plot_grid(NULL, l[[4]], NULL,  l[[5]], NULL,
                    ncol=6, rel_widths=c(0.12,0.34,0.12,0.34,0.06))
plot_grid(top, bottom,
          ncol=1, rel_heights=c(1,1))
```

[image]

You can modify the `rel_widths` in the bottom `plot_grid` call to get it just like you like.

Comment: It works great, thanks! The answer you pointed out also has a very nice-looking solution using `gridExtra`.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a layout with 6 columns and use `NA` for the blanks,

```
library(gridExtra)

p <- ggplot()

grid.arrange(grobs = list(p,p,p,p,p), 
             layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,1,2,2,3,3), c(NA,4,4,5,5,NA)))
```